# Change color of TouchableOpacity in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, touchableopacity

Can anyone help me. 
This is my source code: https://snack.expo.io/rJFgyPDpH

Idea is that, if I click to "**1 Button**" it should be 'red' and if I click to **"2 Button"** is also should change its color to 'red' but the **"1 Button"** should be changed to its default colour which is black. However, **"2 Button"**.

If my approach is too simple, other methods (such as `TouchableHighlight`, ES6 and etc) are also welcomed. I appreciate if you show me mistakes so that I learn from that.

Comment: there is no button/touchable opacity in your app...please have a look once in your code

Comment: Thank you for mentioning, I updated, check it out

Comment: can you pease state what you want....it is not clear in your question...please elaborate on the cases you want

Comment: I want to change background color of Touchableopacity by clicking. Imagine, you have two buttons and both of them have 'black' background colour. If you click to the first button it should be 'red', but second, remains as 'black' background. Consequently, if you click to second button it should be 'red', whereas the first button should be 'black'. I guess now its more clear, if no tell me.

Comment: so lets say button 1 is red and button 2 is black then i clicked on 2 the. it becomes red and then what will happen to button 1?

Comment: it becomes 'black' as default. Because at the beginning both was black, This is kind of active and inactive buttons.

Comment: so you want alternative button color change for both the button....if one is black and another is red then clicking on anyone will reverses the color of the button?

Comment: exactly Abhikumar

Comment: initially both will be black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your code like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state={
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor2: 'black',
    pressed: false,
  };

  changeColor(){
    if(!this.state.pressed){
       this.setState({ pressed: true,backgroundColor: 'red', backgroundColor2: 'black'});
    } else {
      this.setState({ pressed: false, backgroundColor: 'black' ,backgroundColor2: 'red'});
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
              style={{backgroundColor:this.state.backgroundColor, padding: 15}}
              onPress={()=>this.changeColor()}
                >
            <Text style={styles.text}>1 Button</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity
              style={{backgroundColor:this.state.backgroundColor2, padding: 15}}
              onPress={()=>this.changeColor()}
                >
            <Text style={styles.text}>2 button!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text:{
    color:'white'
    },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Now If you click to the first button it should be 'red', but second, remains as 'black' background. Consequently, if you click to second button it should be 'red', whereas the first button should be 'black'.

Answer (score 4):

Try below

```
state={
    selectedButton: '',
};

      <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.selectedButton === 'button1' ? 'red' : 'black', padding: 15}}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedButton: 'button1' })}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>1 Button</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.selectedButton === 'button2' ? 'red' : 'black', padding: 15}}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedButton: 'button2' })}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>2 button!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
```

Comment: I like your answer, it perfectly meets requirement. Since Ravi Sharma first posted answer, I highlighted his answer as a solution. Thank you, for doing this in a simple way)

Answer (score 1):

```
changeColor=()=>{
   this.setState({
      backgroundColor:'red',
      backgroundColor2:'black'
   })
 }

  changeColor2=()=>{
    this.setState({
       backgroundColor:'black',
       backgroundColor2:'red'
   })
 }
```

As per your requirements, onPress on first button, it will invoke changeColor. And onPress of second button, it'll invoke changeColor2.

In the code, onPress of second button, it can be changed to changeColor2 instead of changeColor function.

This

```
 onPress={()=>this.changeColor2()}
```

instead of

```
  onPress={()=>this.changeColor()}
```

Answer (score 1):

By passing id you can change color alternatively

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { colorId:0 };
  }
  onPress = (id) => {
    this.setState({colorId: id});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={this.state.colorId === 1? styles.red : styles.button}
          onPress={()=>this.onPress(1)}>
          <Text>Button1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={this.state.colorId === 2? styles.red : styles.button}
          onPress={()=>this.onPress(2)}>
          <Text>Button2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  red: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

[Live demo](https://snack.expo.io/B1Uz9wvTS)

Comment: Something new for me. Thank you, Vahid. Voted for your answer)))

Answer (score 0):

So all the current approaches manage state with the onPress.

If you view the docs at: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity

The TouchOpacity component inherits all the props of https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#props

Which means you have access to onPressIn and onPressOut which I personally use to manage the state instead of onPress.

Here is my probably overly complicated example, I am using drop shadows and gradients as well:

```
import React, {FC, FormEvent, ReactNode, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, GestureResponderEvent} from 'react-native';
import styled from '@emotion/native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import DropShadow from "react-native-drop-shadow";
import {Theme, useTheme} from "@emotion/react";
import {adjustColor} from "../../helpers";

interface StyledProps {
  fullWidth?: boolean;
  variant?: string;
  activeVariant?: string;
  borderRadius?: string;
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  padding?: string;
  fontSize?: string;
  fontWeight?: string;
  colors?: string[];
  gradient?: boolean;
  active?: boolean;
  isLoading?: boolean;
}

interface ButtonProps<T = GestureResponderEvent> extends StyledProps {
  onPress: ((event: T) => void) | undefined;
  children: ReactNode;
}

const dropShadowProps = {
  shadowColor: "#000",
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  },
  shadowOpacity: .2,
  shadowRadius: 5
}

const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = (props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const {onPress, isLoading, children, ...rest} = props;
  const [active, setActive] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleOnPress = (event: any) => {
    onPress && onPress(event);
  };

  return (
    <StyledButton {...rest}
      onPress={handleOnPress}
      onPressIn={() => setActive(true)}
      onPressOut={() => setActive(false)}
      activeOpacity={props.activeVariant ? 1 : 0.2}
      disabled={isLoading}
    >
      <DropShadow style={active ? {} : dropShadowProps}>
        <StyledGradient colors={getBackgroundColors(props, active, theme)} {...rest}>
          <StyledText {...rest} active={active}>
            {children}
            {isLoading ? (
              <ActivityIndicator color={"#000"} />
            ) : null}
          </StyledText>
        </StyledGradient>
      </DropShadow>
    </StyledButton>
  );
};

const getBackgroundColors = (props: StyledProps, active: boolean, theme: Theme) => {
  const variant = active && props.activeVariant ? props.activeVariant : props.variant;
  const colors = [];

  switch (variant) {
    case "primary":
      colors.push(theme.colors.primary);
      break;
    default:
      colors.push("#ffffff");
  }

  if (props.gradient) {
    colors.push(adjustColor(colors[0], -15));
  } else {
    colors.push(colors[0]);
  }

  return colors;
}

const getColor = (props: any) => {
  const variant = props.active && props.activeVariant ? props.activeVariant : props.variant;

  switch (variant) {
    case "primary":
      return props.theme.colors.white;
    default:
      return props.theme.colors.black;
  }
}

const StyledButton = styled.TouchableOpacity<StyledProps>`
  width: ${props => props.fullWidth ? "100%" : props.width ? props.width : "auto"};
`

const StyledGradient = styled(LinearGradient)<StyledProps>`
  width: ${props => props.fullWidth ? "100%" : props.width ? props.width : "auto"};
  height: ${props => props.height ? props.height : "auto"};
  border-radius: ${props => props.borderRadius ? props.borderRadius : "8px"};
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const StyledText = styled.Text<StyledProps>`
  color: ${props => getColor(props)};
  font-size: ${props => props.fontSize ? props.fontSize : "16px"};
  font-weight: ${props => props.fontWeight ? props.fontWeight : "400"};
  padding: ${props => props.padding ? props.padding : "17px"};
  line-height: ${props => props.fontSize ? props.fontSize : "16px"};
`

export default Button;
```