# How to change the TouchableOpacity image on press

Tags: react-native

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

import check from './assets/icons/covid.png'
import pill from './assets/icons/pill.png'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.containerone}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{borderRadius: 100, height: 150, width: 150, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: 80}}>
          <Image source={pill} style={styles.pillButton}/>
          <Image source={check} style={styles.checkButton}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.containertwo}>
        <Text style={{color:'#982fc2', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:20}}>Text b</Text>
        <Text style={{color:'#982fc2', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:20}}>Text a</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#982fc2'
  },
  containerone: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  containertwo: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderTopRightRadius: 60,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 60,
    padding: 40
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 100,
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    marginTop: 100,
    alignItems:'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  checkButton: {
    height: 130, 
    width: 130, 
    display:'none'
  },
  pillButton: {
    height: 130, 
    width: 130,
    display: 'flex',
    marginTop: 10
  }
});
```

I have a simple question, how can I change the style of two buttons in press the first:
I created one style for each button, the first button is visible, and the second is hidden, so, I want to, when I press the first button, I change it style to display: 'none', and in the second, to display:'flex', can you guys help me?

Comment: This answer can help you as well. [Change Image Color on press](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59207311/11566074)

Comment: I'm having these erros: https://i.imgur.com/dEBqpBo.png

Comment: Can you update your current code? Otherwise, it will be difficult to help you

Comment: I updated the question, read it again, please!

Comment: Ciao, you mean you want to alternate `Image` on `TouchableOpacity` click correct?

Comment: Yes, change the image on press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, you colud use state to alternate Image visibility avoding to use css. Something like:

```
export default function App() {
  const[alternateImage, setAlternateImage] = useState(true);

  const changeImage = () => {
    setAlternateImage(alternateImage => !alternateImage);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.containerone}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{borderRadius: 100, height: 150, width: 150, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: 80}} onPress={changeImage}>
          {alternateImage && <Image source={pill} style={styles.pillButton}/>}
          {!alternateImage && <Image source={check} style={styles.checkButton}/>}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.containertwo}>
        <Text style={{color:'#982fc2', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:20}}>Text b</Text>
        <Text style={{color:'#982fc2', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:20}}>Text a</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and you could remove `display: 'none'` from Image css.

Comment: No problem. Please, mark answer as correct :) Have a nice day!