# setting styles from different places

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have a `TouchableOpacity` with a background color that I want to change depending on a condition.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207062/change-color-of-touchableopacity-in-react-native) they answer how to do it, by controlling the style in the state

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{backgroundColor:this.state.backgroundColor}}
>
```

In my case,  my TouchableOppacity has many style properties, and to keep the code clean I don't want to define all of them inside my render function, since most of them don't depend on any condition.

Usually I do:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>

// and then at the end of the file I define the styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    margin: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
}
```

Now I need to combine both, being able to set the backgroundColor from the state and the rest of the properties from the `styles.button` at the end of the file.

Is there a way to combine styles from different places, so I can have the static ones defined at the end of the file and the dynamic ones inside my class?

I tried something like:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}, styles.button}>
```

But although it sets the styles.button property correctly it doesn't set the backgroundColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by below code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}, styles.button]}>
```

Comment: ahh, I see. I needed an array so styles can be appended, thanks